# Shrink header height by scrollTop value

Tags: jquery, header, height, scrolltop, shrink

Howdey!

Simple problem: I've a fixed header, the height shrinks down based on the `window scrollTop`-value to the half of its height.

What I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="http://yckart.com/ph?text=scroll down" alt>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{padding-top:200%} /* not really needed */

#header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:200px;

    color:#eee;
    background:#222
}

#header img {height:100%; width:auto}
```

**JS**

```
var header = $('#header'),
    headerH = header.height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() <= headerH / 2) {
        header.css({
            height: -($(this).scrollTop() - headerH)
        });
    }
}).scroll();
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/dnz5x/)**.

Works well so far. However, if the user scrolls down e.g. to the bottom and reloads the page, the if statement doesn't work.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: That's because your function gets called only on scroll event, you could put the if statement into a function and call it when the javascript loads.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the scroll event will triggered with `.scroll()` on pageload? But I try your proposal, thanks so far!

Comment: No improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/dnz5x/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the if statement. You need to add an else statement for when the initial scroll state is at the bottom. E.g.:

```
    var header = $('#header'),
    headerH = header.height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() <= headerH / 2) {
        header.css({
            height: -($(this).scrollTop() - headerH)
        });
    } else {
      header.css({
            height: headerH / 2
        });
    }
}).scroll();
```

Comment: @AndrewDyster I have a div that has padding on top, is there any way that the padding can be decreased as well to keep the content centered vertically?