# Jquery slide in div keeps moving on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have aa div that I want to slide in once the user scrolls down a specified amount. It initially works but after than the div keeps moving to the left a little on every scroll action instead of staying in place. Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

```
  var opening = false;
  var closing = false; 
 $(window).scroll(function(){
     var windowHeight = $(window).height();
     var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
     var position1 = $("#Support").offset().top;         
    if ( windowScroll > (position1 - (windowHeight/2)) )  
     {
        if (!opening) {
            opening = true;
            closing = false;
            $("#SupportImage1").stop().animate({
                left: "1200px"                  
              }, 1500, function(){
                  opening = false;
                  });
            }            
     }
     else
     {
        if (!closing) {
            closing = true;
            opening = false;
             $("#SupportImage1").stop().animate({
                left: "100%"                    
              }, 1400, function() {
                  closing = false;
              });                
        }
     }       
 });
```

Comment: Could you give us a JSFiddle? - http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: You mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12350972/

Comment: To be more specific, the image is outside of the page on the right side so it's not visible and when the user scrolls down the specific height I want the image to slide in from the right.

Comment: OK it seems to have fixed itself as I didn't really change the code at all...thanks to everyone for the input!

Answer (score 0):

the scroll bar is most likely affecting your width calculations.

everytime you run that function against the scroll bar you are adding in the total screen width plus the offset by the scroll bar.

Comment: The scroll bar is always there since it's a long page.